# Transform NSInteger to NSString as a 5-digit number

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsinteger, stringwithformat

I have an int and I transform it to a NSString like this:

```
NSString *myStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",myInt];
```

myInt is ranged from 0 to 99999. What I want is to get myStr as a 5-digit number.

for example : 00072 or 09856 or 00002

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `%05d` format specifier in order to pad with zeroes:

```
NSString *myStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%05d", myInt];
```

[Wikipedia's explanation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholders)